# Validation with MongooseJS causing NodeJS app to crash

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to find a better way of performing this validation.  I have the user schmea setup and I'm trying to get the age validation working properly as to not cause the app to crash.  You'll have to forgive me as I'm still relatively new to the language, so I may not be explaining it 100%.  However, here is the User schema I created.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const validator = require('validator')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    age: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        validate(value) {
            if(value < 13){
                throw new Error('You must be over the age of 13 to register for this site!')
            }
        }
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true,
        validate(value){
            if (!validator.isEmail(value)) {
                throw new Error('Email is invalid')
            }
        }
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        minlength: 7,
        validate(value){
            if (value.toLowerCase().includes('password')) {
                throw new Error('Password cannot contain "password"')
            }
        }
    },
    tokens: [{
        token: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }]
})

userSchema.virtual('tasks', {
    ref: 'Task',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'owner'
})

userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = async function () {
    const user = this
    const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id.toString() }, 'thisismynewcourse')

    user.tokens = user.tokens.concat({ token })
    await user.save()

    return token
}

userSchema.statics.findByCredentials = async (email, password) => {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email })

    if (!user) {
        throw new Error('Unable to login')
    }

    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)

    if (!isMatch) {
        throw new Error('Unable to login')
    }

    return user
}

//Hash the plain text password before saving
userSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
    const user = this

    if (user.isModified('password')) {
        user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 8)
    }

    next()
})

userSchema.methods.toJSON = function () {
    const user = this
    const userObject = user.toObject()

    delete userObject.password
    delete userObject.tokens

    return userObject
}

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)

module.exports = User
```

The exact area that I'm trying to hone in on is in the age section, I'm trying to validate ages 13 or older, and when I run a test user creation through post man it performs the validation correctly, but it stops the application with the following:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: User validation failed: age: You must be over the age of 13 to register
```

Is there a way that I can prevent the application from crashing or should I perform the validation else where?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the validation is performed in another file. This can be considered to be a service. But it should pass through a controller first if you want to do it properly. Here is an example of a simple blog post schema I made. You can see the function at the bottom runs every time before I send it to the database.

This is how it looks like in my schema file looks like which is located in folder called models.

```
// Requiring modules
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Initializing Schema
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Creating a data model
const schema = new Schema({
    shopname : {type: String, required:true},
    address : {type: String, required:true},
    review : {type: String, required:false},

    image : {type: String, required:false},
    originalname: {type: String, required:false},
    filename: {type: String, required:false},
    mimetype: {type: String, required:false},
    size : {type: String, required:false},

    updatedAt: {type: Date, required:false},
    createdAt: {type: Date, required:false}
})

// Settings up the process before the data is sent to mongoDB.
// This process is call everytime 'save' is called.
// it sets the data for createdAt and updatedAt.
schema.pre('save', function(next){
    if (!this.createdAt){
        this.createdAt = new Date();
    }else{
        this.updatedAt = new Date();
    }
    next();
})

// Exports module
module.exports = mongoose.model("Blog", schema);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would I pass that error along to the user from within there, or should I do it in say the user router file?

Comment: I would do it on the frontend (would be the easiest way)! If it can't be done there, I would do it in the router file. You can use the Express-flash to achieve this. https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-flash

The easiest way to stop your app from crashing would be to use the try & catch method. You can read more about it here >>>> 
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp

Comment: I tried it within the router file within the try catch I have there, I have an if else statement where if the age on `user.age` isn't greater then 13 it shouldn't run.  But for some reason it still generates the user.  Any way to stop this, I'm reading documentation to see if I can find a way to stop it.

Comment: Yeah, here is an example `router.post('/users', async (req, res) => {
    const user = new User(req.body)
    const token = await user.generateAuthToken()

    try {

        if (user.age < 13) {
            return res.status(400).send('You must be over the age of 13 to join this site!')
        } else {
            await user.save()
            res.status(201).send({ user, token })
        }
    }catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }
})`

It's a little jumbled in this code block, but I'm not quite sure how else to post it.

Comment: Hmmmm I tried your code and it seems to work fine for me! Can you check what do you receive in the user.age variable. Maybe console.log it and check it out. I suspect something is wrong over there

Comment: Yeah, the code operates as it should, it gets the right responses, but it's still creating the mongoDB document for that user so it's still running the user.save() lines in the else statement